# Checkbox will never check - even when value is true

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a checkbox with a condition that checks whether an `id` is within the `Set`. If so, it should check, if not it should remain unchecked. However, even if it is true, the checkbox will not check for some reason and I can't figure out why.

```
  const [ checkedAccounts, setCheckedAccounts ] = React.useState(new Set());

  const toggleChecked = (id) => {
    if (checkedAccounts.has(id)) {
      checkedAccounts.delete(id);
    } else {
      checkedAccounts.add(id);
    }
  };

  const toggleAllChecked = (ids) => {
    if (!checkedAccounts.size) {
      setCheckedAccounts(new Set(ids));
    } else {
      setCheckedAccounts(new Set());
    }
  };

return (
...
<Table.Header>
 <Table.Row>
  <Table.HeaderCell>
   <div>Select All</div> 
   <Checkbox onChange={() => toggleAllChecked(allIds)}/>
  </Table.HeaderCell>
 </Table.Row>
</Table.Header>

 {data?.map((delta, idx) => (
    <Table.Row key={idx}>
       <Table.Cell>
         <Checkbox onChange={() => toggleChecked(delta.accountId)}
                   checked={checkedAccounts.has(delta.accountId)}/>
       </Table.Cell>
     </Table.Row>
...
```

When I use the `toggleAllChecked` function, it will check all of the checkboxes. However, when I use `toggleChecked` function, the `id` will be added/removed from the set as the checkbox is clicked but the checkbox will remain unchecked and I have no idea why.

Comment: Seems like an infinite loop, similar to that described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32923255/react-checkbox-doesnt-toggle). Basically, because you're toggling the checkbox state onChange, it will keep firing back and forth when you run your function.

If this doesn't help, please provide the Checkbox element definition for further clarity.

Comment: @justathoughtor2 Do you have a solution to this error? The checkbox is basically the same is a regular html input of type checkbox. It just needs the checked prop to be either true or false.

Here is the checkbox: https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/checkbox/

Comment: Check the answers to the question I linked.

Comment: I checked the answers and have tried using it in my code but it's still not checked. Maybe I'm doing this wrong. What would your suggestion be?

Comment: @justathoughtor2 Just to add, the answers in the question differ quite a lot from my case and I'm unsure how to prevent the infinite loop. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is there any chance you can provide a CodePen example or something similar to test against? I'm not able to replicate from my end without additional context.

Comment: In `toggleChecked()`, you are mutating state directly. You need to update it using `setCheckedAccount()` for it to re-render.

Comment: @Calvin Yep, that was the issue. I was mutating state directly! I thought since it was a Set, i could do that but I was wrong

Comment: One of the problems with mutating state directly is that React doesn't know of the change and thus doesn't know it needs to render the component again.